# New presentation

Tags: beamer

I am thinking, can anyone tell me which beamer template (actually if it is made with latex) is the  figure below

[image]

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Well, you can check if it is made by LaTeX with at least some reliability by looking at the file's properties e.g. in your PDF viewer. Beyond that: many programmes can draw indistinct bluish blurs.

Comment: @Andrew I don't have the pdf, I found this picture by chance, I like it and I want to do my final graduate project like this

Comment: Once again, this is a [crosspost](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=27347). By not marking them as such, you are violating the board rules of LaTeX-community.org.

Comment: I would write a poiite email to the authors, because *they know*, whereas everybody here can only *guess*.

Answer (score 1):

Could be the `Singapore` theme

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Singapore}


\begin{document}

    \section{Test}
    \begin{frame}
        abc
    \end{frame}     

    \section{Test2}
    \begin{frame}
        abc
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]